# Releasing connection in connectionDidFinishLoading cause bad instruction

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, network-programming

According to **URL Loading System Programming Guide** `NSConnection` sample code I can release connection in `connectionDidFailWithError` and `connectionDidFinishLoading`.

However, releasing connection in `connectionDidFinishLoading` causing

```
objc[19685]: FREED(id): message releaseDelegate sent to freed object=0x3b41630
Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION”.
```

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you doesn't retain the object you receive from [NSConnection connectionWithRequest:] then you must not call release on it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a double release error. It means either you didn't `retain` an object enough times, or you sent it too many `release` messages.

Comment: I understand the nature of error, but all I do is just create `NSConnection` with `connectionWithRequest` and then release in those 2 delegates. The rest of the bodies of delegate methods are empty.

Comment: The general rule is: If you don't create objects using alloc, and don't retain objects, you don't have to release them. They will magically disappear when no-one needs them anymore (with NSAutoReleasePool being the magician and autorelease being the magic spell)